# UICollectionView Reloading cells backwards

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, reloaddata

I am using a UICollectionView as a square grid layout for a crossword. The user will 'create' the puzzle by first tapping each cell to change the colour, press the 'insert numbers button' then add the numbers for each square and finally press the 'get clues button'. When the 'insert numbers button' is pressed, the cells are reloaded to 'fix' the colour and a textfield for each square's number is unhidden (for white cells only). The problem arises when I reload the cells to make the square's number un-editable, the cells reload in reverse. I.e. if the first cell (index 0) has a number, the last cell is updated (index 63). Pressing the button twice puts the cells in the correct position.

I have printed the indexPath to see which cell has the text and it is always the reverse...

Code:

```
import UIKit

class gridSetup: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
UICollectionViewDelegate {

var setColours: Bool = true
var setNumbers: Bool = false
var numbers: Array = [Int]()
var whiteSquares:Array = [IndexPath]()
var gridSizer: Int?    //value passed in from previous screen

@IBOutlet weak var getCluesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var insertNumbersButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var grid: UICollectionView!

let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setColours = true
    setNumbers = false
    getCluesButton.isHidden = true

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return (self.gridSizer * self.gridSizer)
    return (self.gridSizer! * self.gridSizer!)
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    if setColours == true {
        whiteSquares.append(indexPath) //initalise whiteSquares by adding all the squares
        cell.cellGuess.isHidden = true  //hide the letter guesses
        cell.squareNumber.isHidden = true   //hide the sqaure numbers
    }

    //redraw cells to fix the colours

    // if we are on a white cell and are done setting colours
    if setColours == false && whiteSquares.contains(indexPath) == true {
        if setNumbers == true {
            cell.squareNumber.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            if cell.squareNumber.text != "" {

                print("I have a number inside, Index: ", indexPath.row)


            }
            cell.squareNumber.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.squareNumber.placeholder = ""
            cell.cellGuess.isHidden = false
            return cell
        }
        }

    // on a black square
    else if setColours == false && whiteSquares.contains(indexPath) == false {
        cell.squareNumber.isHidden = true
        //print("on a black square", indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.squareNumber.isHidden = true
        cell.cellGuess.isHidden = true   
    }
        //initial grid setup
    else {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.squareNumber.isHidden = true
    }

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return cell
}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    //print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

}

// change background color back when user releases touch
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    if setColours == true {
        if cell?.backgroundColor == UIColor.black {
            //print("add", indexPath.row)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            var k: Int = 0
            for i in whiteSquares {

                if indexPath.row < i.row {
                    whiteSquares.insert(indexPath, at: k)
                    break
                }
                else {
                    k += 1
                }
            }

            }
        else {
            //print("remove", indexPath.row)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            var k: Int = 0
            for i in whiteSquares {

                if indexPath.row == i.row {
                    whiteSquares.remove(at: k)
                }
                else {
                    k += 1
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@IBAction func getClues(_ sender: Any) {
    setNumbers = false
    grid.reloadData()   //problem comes from/after calling this function
}

@IBAction func insertNumbers(_ sender: Any) {
    setColours = false
    insertNumbersButton.isHidden = true
    setNumbers = true
    getCluesButton.isHidden = false
    grid.reloadData()

}
}
// some layout stuff, (not important)
extension gridSetup: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / (CGFloat(gridSizer! + 1))
    //let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / (CGFloat(gridSizer! + 1))
    let height = width

    return  CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
}
```

The '1' should be in the 1st row, second column

[image: '1' should be in the second cell]

Comment: There is a lot of code there and it is hard to see what is happening but `cellForItemAt` can be called in any order. As long as your data model correctly reflects the state of each cell and that function correctly configures the cell based on the model it all should work. There seems to be a lot more code in your `cellForItemAt` than I would have thought necessary. Start by creating a struct to represent each cell; consider its properties: Black/white, numbered, editable etc then create an array of these and then use that array to configure each cell.

Comment: Would the struct method rely on knowing before hand what the properties of each cell in the grid would be? The idea was to use the collectionView to determine the cell properties to transcribe a real crossword into the digital domain.

Comment: The array of structs is how you know what the properties of each cell should be; cells are simply views onto data.  You should not rely on the cell as a data store in itself.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Thanks for your help and fast responses!

Comment: And you'll notice that it is just as if cells were dequeued in reverse order. As explained above, cells are not for storage. What I did here is have a property to store the selected key, and use this property where needed, such as in cellForItemAt